# Redirect loop when trying to log in for first time with Google account

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I tried to login for the first time with my Google account. I may have already created an Askubuntu account years ago using the same gmail address. Now it sends me in a redirect loop when I click on "Ask Question".

Using stock Firefox on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Where/what does it redirect you to?

Comment: It depends on the link I clicked. If I clicked on Ask Question, it would bring me to the Login page, the banner would pop up at the top saying "Welcome Back! redirecting you", and then redirect me to the exact same page. This was an endless loop.

Answer (score 2):

I found the cause of this, it is probably related to Firefox and some old, old cookies. I have sinced switch to 2-FA on google, and this probably had something to do with it. I cleared all cookies and re-logged in and all is well.